# Kартинка не обновляется jsf

Tags: java, изображения, jsf

Извлекаю из базы данных строки, изображение, дату помещаю значения в поля ввода изменяю и произвожу "апдейт",- работает все кроме изображения!
Помогите разобраться!

Сервлет для извлечения картинки:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse)throws ServletException,IOException{
        Statement statement= null;
        ResultSet resultSet;
        InputStream inputStream;
        String SQL;
        try {
            String fileId= httpRequest.getParameter("Id");
            System.out.println("inside servlet�>" +fileId);
            Connection connection= databaseConnect.getConnection();
            statement= connection.createStatement();
            SQL= "SELECT file FROM Registration WHERE id= '"+fileId+"'";
             resultSet= statement.executeQuery(SQL);
              if(resultSet.next()){
                byte[]byteArray= new byte[524288];
                int size= 0;
                inputStream= resultSet.getBinaryStream(1);
                httpResponse.reset();
                httpResponse.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                 while((size= inputStream.read(byteArray))!= -1){
                     httpResponse.getOutputStream().write(byteArray, 0, size);
                 }
              }
        } catch(IOException eIO) {
            System.out.println("I/O error in retreiveImage servlet"+eIO);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in retreiveImage servlet"+e);
        }
    }
```

Вывод изображения на страницу:

```
<h:outputLink id="file" value="retreiveImage?Id=#{bean.id}" target="_blank">
 <h:graphicImage value="retreiveImage?Id=#{bean.id}" width="50" height="75">
 <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}"></h:inputFile>// Попытка вставить новое изображение
 </h:graphicImage>
```

Метод, который обновляет (апдейт) данные:

```
public static String updateUserRecord(manager updateRecord){
        try {
            SQL= "UPDATE Registration SET userName=?, email=?, password=?, file=?, timeStamp=? WHERE id=?";
            prepStatement= databaseConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
            prepStatement.setString(1, updateRecord.getUserName());
            prepStatement.setString(2, updateRecord.getEmail());
            prepStatement.setString(3, updateRecord.getPassword());
            inputStream= file.getInputStream();
            prepStatement.setBinaryStream(4, inputStream, (int)file.getSize());
            //create a java timestamp object that represents the current time ("current timestamp")
            Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
            Timestamp timeStamp= new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
            prepStatement.setTimestamp(5, timeStamp);
            prepStatement.setInt(6, updateRecord.getId());
            prepStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("User updated Successfully!");
            FacesMessage message= new FacesMessage("User updated!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("editForm: updateBtn", message);
            prepStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "administration";
    }
```

Comment: И? Что конкретно не работает? Картинка не показывается в `<h:graphicImage>`? Или не загружается выбранная в `<h:inputFile>`? Ошибки какие-нибудь вылетают?

Comment: Выбранная картинка не загружается в <h:inputFile>!

Comment: Значения инпутов типа _file_ могут устанавливаться только пользователем и могут содержать только ссылки на **локальные файлы**, которые пользователь **собирается** загрузить. Загруженные файлы в них не отображаются.

Comment: Подскажите, т.е. картинку можно и не выгружать для обновления? А заменить ее новой картинкой? Вставкой нового файла?

Comment: Именно. Загружая новую картинку, вы заменяете старую.

Comment: Тогда для картинки insert или update запрос делать? Если insert тогда картинку нужно отдельным методом менять?!

Comment: Проверяете наличие в бине идентификтора: если он есть, делаете update, если нет, то insert.

Comment: Идентификатора картинки? Подскажите какой должен быть идентификатор?

Comment: В bean добавьте поле и сохраняйте в него id строки с картинкой в БД.